# Upgrade From Snow Leopard Desktop to Snow Leopard Server

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-server

I just installed Snow Leopard on my Mac Pro and it's running great! I upgraded it from 10.5 and it worked just fine for me. I was looking at the Snow Leopard Server and all the features it offers for the other Macs on my home network. My question is this: Can I install Snow Leopard Server on my Mac Pro without having to do a clean install? I have everything set up perfectly and I really don't want to have to reconfigure everything.

My other question is, besides the server software, is there any difference between the server and desktop versions? More specifically, am I still going to be able to use my audio creation/editing software and play the few games I have? Does the server strip out any functionality or is it exactly the same thing as the desktop version, but with added server tools?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Snow Leopard Server in place of Snow Leopard on my Mac mini because I had no experience with Mac Os X Server OS !

After 5 months of daily use, I can say it's very close to Snow Leopard except for server dedicated functions (users management, server applications, ...).

There is no restriction for you about playing games or running creation/editing software !

About the clean installation :

I'm not sure you can install Snow Leopard Server over Snow Leopard while keeping your configuration because some stuff are stored differently.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do an upgrade installation of Snow Leopard Server(SLS) - unsurprisingly it's not something Apple ever planned for...

If you were to install SLS over the top of your existing SL install it would cause quite a few issues - file permissions/ownership etc etc.  You would probably not retain any settings and you would have to reinstall most of your programs so there is really no point.

Grab a copy of Parallels or VMWare Fusion and virtualise SLS if you really can't lose your current install.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the services you want to offer you might want to look into: http://cutedgesystems.com/

The client version pretty much has all the services build-in with a few exceptions, no GUIs and no preconfiguration. The tools from Cutedgesystems are a great help and sometimes do the job even better than OSX Server and it's GUI

Together with the sharing options in System Preferences you should be able to set up a Server without any reinstallation.